Tree of addition chains
Addition chains are a well-known way of building up a number from 1 by adding two previously computed numbers. It is a long-standing open problem to determine the complexity of computing the length of the shortest addition chain to obtain a given number $n$. In Knuth TAOCP Vol 2, Section 4.6.3, devoted to the topic, on Figure 15 there is a tree depecting the shortest addition chains for $n\le 100$. A fastest way of computing a given number can be obtained by tracing your way along the tree from a given number to the root 1. However, in general I see no way why addition chains should form a tree.

Is there an $n$ such that all shortest addition chains to derive $n$ do not include any shortest addition chains for the number computed just before $n$ in the addition chain, or more generally, for any $n/2\le i<n$?


Neill Clift ran a search for $n\le2^{21}$ looking for an example of an $n=a_r$ such that $l(a_{r-1}) > r-1$ for all chains, and couldn't find any.
